# How do i pass a number to a generic?

Tags: java

I have a generic called Array. How can i pass the size of the array to the generic?

```
public class Array<insert size here?> {
    
    private int size;
    
    public int GetSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Either create a `constructor` that takes in the size or create a `set` method for doing so. I believe what you are questioning is the type of objects which are held in the `array`.

Comment: The type of elements in the array and the size of the array are entirely unrelated.  You may need to go back to some tutorials about generics and what they mean, because this isn't it.

Comment: Generics can only be types. This is *not* the same as templates in C++, where you can do things like this.

Comment: Ok thank you.So i have to pass the size to the constructor if i really want to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have misunderstood the Generic concept. And also I see you are confused about two things here that are the constructor and generic. So my answer is based on that.

#### Generic

> Generic classes are classes that take a type as a parameter.

But here I see you are trying to get the array size as the class parameter. Generic is not for this. You can use your constructor to pass the array Size.

In this way you can create a generic class that allow to pass the size of the array.

```java
public class MyGenericArray<T> {

    private int size;
    ArrayList<T> array;

    public MyGenericArray(int size) {
        this.array = new ArrayList<T>(size);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Here into `T` you can pass any type such as String, Integer, Boolean. That will decide what type of Array you will get. You can use the constructor to pass the size of the array. You can create a new object from your generic class like this.

```java
MyGenericArray<Integer> array = new MyGenericArray<>(5);
```

Here I have passed `Integer` into `T`. So you will have `MyGenericArray` of type `Integer`. I have passed 5 to the constructor which sets the size of the array.

PS: This is just to understand the Generic type and Constructor. Not the best way you can do this.